# For two functions $f,g$ from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ how should I interpret $f \wedge g$?

Tags: functions, notation

For two functions $f,g$ from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ how should I interpret $f \wedge g$? I came to such a term while reading the axioms of fuzzy topology.

Comment: More context might be necessary. Can you provide the source for where you are getting the axioms of fuzzy topology?

Comment: In analysis, $f \wedge g$ usually means the function $h$ defined by $h(x) = \min\{f(x), g(x)\}$. Not sure about fuzzy topology, though.

Answer (score 1):

Wedge product of two $0$-forms (AKA smooth functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$) is ordinary multiplication. This could be what they mean.